# Fill td with empty div contenteditable

Tags: html, css, html-table, contenteditable

I have many empty (without content) contenteditable div`s in td. I need div's width:100% and height:100% of td.

HTML:

```
<td>
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
td {min-width: 100px; min-height: 120px; width: 100%; height: 100%}
td div{height: 100%; width: 100%; display:inline-block;}
```

This works if div has content in it, but if it's empty I can't see it and can't change its content (div has `width:0; height:0`).

Answer (score 5):

The usual trick is to put `&nbsp;` (which is a so-called escape sequence) into the table cell.

The CSS line `table { empty-cells: show; }` is also a solution.

For more information, click here: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html

Comment: I used `&nbsp;` trick. Such an easy solution but I couldn`t find it myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could set the min-height to the div instead td too :), at least , you learned something ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow:hidden` on the `div` to make it fill the `td`.

Comment: This doesn`t work... But thanks for response anyway!)

Comment: I've tried your code in JSFiddle and it works out of the box. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/t51aj0s8/

Comment: Doesn`t in FF 31. Tried same code in latest Crome and Opera works fine. I already used &nbsp; trick. It looks like universal solution/